# GHC: Why does type ambiguity go away when using let

Tags: haskell, typechecking

I have a type class

```
class (Monad f) => Test f where
  test :: () -> f ()
```

and an instance

```
instance Test (ErrorT String (Identity)) where
  test pat = return pat
```

If I run a monad stack referring to this instance, GHC can't find out what monad I am talking about (in a `do` block of the `Either String` monad):

```
rhs' <- runIdentity $ runErrorT $ test rhs
```

yields the error message:

```
Ambiguous type variable `f0' in the constraint:
  (Test f0) arising from a use of `test'
  ...
```

But if I bind the part `test rhs` to a variable:

```
let action = test rhs
rhs' <- runIdentity $ runErrorT $ action
```

it works, even though the variable is used nowhere else so nothing new can be inferred about it.

How is this possible, if I have added no information for the type checker to use? Why can't it figure out the type of the equivalent first formulation? Or are the two formulations not equivalent? What part of the Haskell type checker (or desugaring rules?) did I not understand here?

I am using the extensions `MultiParamTypeClasses`, `FlexibleInstances` and `ScopedTypeVariables`

edit: I simplified the example so the strange issue occurs without needing the rest of my code (and with a shorter monad stack), but now it looks nonsensical. The full context of the statement is:

```
doStuff :: (Map Int ()) -> Either String (Map Int ())
doStuff g = run (snd . head . Map.toList $ g) g where
 run :: () -> Map Int () -> Either String (Map Int ())
 run rhs g = do
  let action = test rhs 
  rhs' <- runIdentity $ runErrorT $  test rhs -- or: action
  return g
```

Comment: Can you cut this down to a small reproducible example? There are too many external things in this code to try this out ourselves - e.g. `Pattern`, `Symbol`, `g` and `rhs`.

Comment: I think in your cutdown code, the ambiguity comes from `let action = test rhs` if you don't use `action`. If I use `test rhs` and also delete the `let action =` line, it compiles fine.

Comment: Also, assuming this isn't the problem with your original code, what happens if you don't use `$`, i.e. write something like `runIdentity (runErrorT (test rhs))` ? It's just a guess but at certain points there have been some funny rules to help `runST $ ...` typecheck and it's just possible they are relevant here.

Comment: I get an error only if the `let` is left around when `action` is unused. This confirms what @GaneshSittampalam suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

```
doStuff :: (Map Int ()) -> Either String (Map Int ())
doStuff g = run (snd . head . Map.toList $ g) g where
 run :: () -> Map Int () -> Either String (Map Int ())
 run rhs g = do
  rhs' <- runIdentity $ runErrorT $  test rhs
  return g
```

or

```
doStuff :: (Map Int ()) -> Either String (Map Int ())
doStuff g = run (snd . head . Map.toList $ g) g where
 run :: () -> Map Int () -> Either String (Map Int ())
 run rhs g = do
  let action = test rhs
  rhs' <- runIdentity $ runErrorT $ action
  return g
```

should type check without issue.  The problem is

```
doStuff :: (Map Int ()) -> Either String (Map Int ())
doStuff g = run (snd . head . Map.toList $ g) g where
 run :: () -> Map Int () -> Either String (Map Int ())
 run rhs g = do
  let action = test rhs
  rhs' <- runIdentity $ runErrorT $ action
  return g
```

the reason for this is that you seem to have MonoLocalBinds or the Monomorphism Restriction enabled which prevents generalizations of the binding to `action` unless the type is known.

Comment: That explains it. Though it still does not explain why in my original code (where there is a type variable) I wasn't able to give a type signature to `action`. I have `ScopedTypeVariables` enabled but I get the typical error message about rigid type variables.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Monomorphism Restriction tripped me up, together with the fact that I left the unused binding in the code when switching between the two versions (I thought I didn't and it wouldn't matter, but it did). So the type of `action` could not be inferred down to a monomorphic type.

There is still an open issue: In my original code, I use a Polymorphic type `(Pattern s)` everywhere you now see `()`. The compiler suggests in the error message that I add a type signature for `action` to fix the polymorphism, but confusingly I can't: Even with `ScopedTypeVariables` I get the error message `Couldn't match type 's1' with 's3' ...` about rigid type variables bound in the type signatures for `run` and `action`. But I guess that is another question, so I consider this one answered. Thank you.